# How do you find the multivariable equation that gives you a certain range away from another equation at the minimum?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, elliptic-functions

Sorry if this is phrased weird, I don't have background in math whatsoever.

Is there a way to find the function $F$ that gives you Cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)$ with just the knowledge of $F(t) - G(t) = \text{given range}$ i.e. $\sqrt{(x_f - x_g)^2 + (y_f - y_g)^2 + (z_f - z_g)^2} = R$; and $F'(t) - G'(t) = 0$ i.e. at the minimum range? They are both ellipses if that helps. I have the initial $x, y, z, \dot{x}, \dot{y}$, and $\dot{z}$ of $F(t)$ at $t_0$ and all of the data on $G$ including $\dot{x}$, $\dot{y}$, and $\dot{z}$. The $\dot{x}$, $\dot{y}$, and $\dot{z}$ are going to change to form a new ellipse that has the minimum distance equal to the given range. I am realizing that it might be a family of functions that will get that answer or a sphere of possible $x, y, z$ coordinates at the minimum time. I wasn't sure if it could be calculated so I can optimize that sphere down to a point based on the minimum amount of change from the $\dot{x}$, $\dot{y}$, and $\dot{z}$ of $F(t)$. If the 3-Dimensional solution doesn't work but a 2-Dimensional one would then I'll take that too.

Comment: So you're trying to find the minimum length of an ellipse? Preferably given by some function?

Comment: How is it that a person with no background in math whatsoever is able to talk meaningfully about vector calculus?  Anyway, my real question is: Do you mean that the distance from $F(t)$ to $G(t)$ is fixed for all $t$. If so, your later remark about "minimum range" doesn't make sense. Nor can they both be ellipses (the fixed distance offset from an ellipse is not another ellipse).

Comment: @Tiwa, no I'm trying to find the distance from a point on two ellipses that changes with time.

Comment: And @Paul, I probably exaggerated a bit about no background whatsoever, I took up to Calc 2 in college but they didn't go over stuff like this haha. $F(t)$ and $G(t)$ change with time and the distance between them won't be the same at different times. I'm trying to create the $F(t)$ that gives a minimum distance away from $G(t)$ throughout a time interval of one time around the ellipse.

Comment: Also I can't assume that the points start at the same anomaly on the ellipses, I want to find a way to test it based on that difference in anomaly and difference in orientation of the ellipses. I can limit it to the ellipses being in the same plane (hence the 2D being okay) but if I can find the 3D solution that would be astronomically better.